# Execute an sql query in umbraco at time of package Installation

Tags: umbraco

I have created a package in umbraco and trying to add Action Script which will create a table in umbraco database.But When I try to save the below action script it is giving error message:

**Actions XML is malformed, either remove the text in the actions field or make sure it is correctly formed XML.**

I am not able to identify what's the mistake I am doing here in below code.Please Help me out here. Thanks in advance.

**Note: I am using Umbraco 4.8.0**

```
    <Action runat="install" undo="false" alias="ExecuteSql">
<![CDATA
        CREATE TABLE [test_nishantBlog_Comment](
            [__kp_ID] [smallint] IDENTITY(1999,1) NOT NULL,
            [__fk_postID] [smallint] NOT NULL,
            [Comment] [ntext] NOT NULL,
            [CreationTime] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
            [CommentTitle] [varchar](500) NOT NULL,
            [EmailAdd] [varchar](100) NULL,
         CONSTRAINT [PK_test_nishantBlog_Comment] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
        (
            [__kp_ID] ASC
        )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
        ) 
    ]>

</Action>
```

Comment: Here is link: For Execute sql action script: http://nishantwork.wordpress.com/2012/08/24/execute-sql-query-in-umbraco-during-package-installation/

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the square brackets around your SQL

```
<![CDATA[-- SQL goes here --]]>
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is the ] characters in the SQL statement are causing issues with the CDATA close brackets: "]>"

Could you remove those and see if it works?